# How to set multiple SSIS variables in SQL Task

Tags: sql, ssis

Say I want to get the key values of two tables and assign to two package variables.

I can easily assign one, setting the Execute SQL Task to return a single row. But is it possible to set multiple variables with multiple result sets?

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(LogKey),0) AS LogKey FROM Log
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(HeaderKey),0) AS HKey FROM Header
```

I've tried setting the `ResultSet` property to both single row and Full result set, but neither seem to work. Do I have to use a separate Execute SQL task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this to force the values on the same resultset:

```
SELECT
A = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(LogKey),0) AS LogKey FROM Log),
B = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(HeaderKey),0) AS HrKey FROM Header)
```